# Incorrect value being passed in to SQL from .NET sqlcommand

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Why when I run the below code, which should insert a value of 122387593.6 into the table, does it insert a value of 122387593.59999999?

I have traced the call made by .net and can see the value is being passed in as 122387593.59999999 to SQL, yet while debugging the parameter value is returned as 122387593.6?!

I have not been able to work out why .NET is doing this - any help is greatly appreciated.

```
   ---SQL Code

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblNum](
[Num] [numeric](28, 8) NOT NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]


   CREATE PROCEDURE spNumInsert (@Num numeric(28,8))
   AS
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tblNum VALUES(@Num)
   END
   GO

   --.NET Code

    Dim a = Double.Parse("122387593.6", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=server;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spNumInsert", con)
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Num", a))

    con.Open()
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
```

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`double` means IEEE754. IEEE754 *cannot express* every single value. It is quite possible that `122387593.6` *does not exist* in IEEE754, and that `122387593.59999999` is the nearest approximation.

If you need values that match what us meat-headed humans tend to agree on as the "exact" approximation (note the contradiction in terms), you should be using `decimal`, not `double`.

To be clear: both `decimal` and `double` are forced to approximate - there is only so much you can do to fit such a range of possible values into finite bytes. But the *way* they approximate is different. `decimal` is appropriate for discrete measurements like money; `double` is appropriate for continuous measurements.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Double.Parse`. You need to use `Decimal`.

Your object `a` is already 122387593.59999999 because this is how 122387593.6 must be represented in the floating point standard, which is what double is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with precision of double in .NET. If you checkout variable `a` after this line

```
Dim a = Double.Parse("122387593.6", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You will notice that it has already wrong value. You can try to use `decimal` it is more precise.

Answer (score -3):

use function

```
  ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ]  )
```